# Initial discounts for memberships or recurring payments

Tags: cividiscount, stripe

After leaving Paypal for Stripe, I am trying to get my members to re-build their recurring payments (memberships).  To incentivize them I am trying to give them an initial discount on their first payment so that at the renewal (second payment) it renews at the regular rate again.  Unfortunately the discounted rate seems to be renewing again and again in Stripe past the date that the rules of the discount set forth.

How do I set it up so that on the initial membership the user pays the discounted rate, then on the recurring payment pays at the regular rate?

I am running the following on Wordpress.

- CiviCRM 5.29.0
- Stripe Payment Processor 6.5.7
- CiviDiscount 3.8.1
- Payment Shared (mjwshared) 0.9.11

Comment: Could  you clarify a bit?  Is a "renewal" the next payment in a recurring payment series? Or is it someone starting a new recurring payment series?

Comment: The next payment in a recurring payment series.

Comment: This is something you would need to change on the Stripe side: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade